# Route to User page from first segment

Tags: routes, user-profile

I am building a site for a travel agency. Each agent needs to have his/her own public profile page. I want each agent's profile page to be accessed at `agencyname.com/agentname`, with `agentname` being the agent's username. This would load an agent profile template populated with the given agent's profile data.

I still need other non-agent segment-1 pages to continue working also, like `agencyname.com/cruises` or `agencyname.com/group-travel`. These would be 'normal' template pages.

Is there any way to make this work dynamically? Creating a dynamic route with only a token in Segment 1 breaks access to other regular pages. I don't want to have to create a hard route every time we add an agent, and we don't want to add another segment like `agencyname.com/agent/agentname`. We want the URL each agent puts on their business card to be as clean and easy to remember as possible.

I'm thinking something along the lines of this logic:

```
If Segment 1 matches a username
   Display the profile template for that user
Else
   Continue routing per the normal routing checks
```

I don't have the knowledge to build a plugin, or the budget for someone else to. I'm seeking solutions that could be implemented without a plugin (unless there's already a plugin available).

Any constructive thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a check at the top of all of your templates that tests if the first uri segment matches one the agent names.

```
{% set firstSegment = craft.request.firstSegment %}
{% set agents = craft.users.group('agents') %}
{% for agent in agents %}
    {% set agentName = agent.firstName ~ "-" ~ agent.lastName %}
    {% if firstSegment == agentName %}
        {% set requestedAgent = agent %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if requestedAgent is defined %}
    {% include 'users/_profile' with { user: requestedAgent } only %}
{% else %}
    {% extend 'layouts/_main' %}

    ... normal page template goes here

{% endif %}
```

In your profile template you should now have a variable 'user' available with the requested agent.

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{% user.firstName %} {% user.lastName %}</h1>
    <p>...</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That worked well. Here's what I ended up doing.

`{% set aname = craft.request.firstSegment %}
{% if aname %}
  {% set agentObj = craft.users.username(aname).search('publicProfile:1').last() %}
  {% if agentObj | length %}{% redirect 'agent/' ~ agentObj.username | lower %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}`

Comment: I really hate that you can't format code in comments.